# resample('H').ohlc()でAttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, azure

PythonにてOHLC形式でリサンプリングしたく、以下のコードを記述しましたが、AttributeErrorとなってしまいます。
何が悪いかわかる方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

なお実行環境はAzureMLのPythonScriptです。

ソース：

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe1['Time'], unit='s')
dataframe1.index = dataframe1['Time']
x = dataframe1.resample('H').ohlc()
```

dataframe1：

```
           Time     Open     High      Low    Close 
20170102 020100  116.875  116.915  116.875  116.901 
20170102 020200  116.901  116.901  116.901  116.901 
20170102 020300  116.901  116.906  116.897  116.900
```

エラーメッセージ：

```
Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information:
---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------
Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 199, in batch
    odfs = mod.azureml_main(*idfs)
  File "C:\temp\16dad51ce7994c25aa02a0a388e26709.py", line 44, in azureml_main
    x = dataframe1.resample('H').ohlc()
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1843, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ohlc'
Process returned with non-zero exit code 1

---------- End of error message from Python  interpreter  ----------
```

以上です。
よろしくお願いします。

#### 7/17追記

magichanさんご回答ありがとうございます。
おっしゃる通り、すでにOHLC形式になっていますね...
目的の説明が間違っておりました。正しくは「OHLC形式のデータをリサンプリングしたい」です。
教えていただいたソースを以下のように試してみましたが、同じようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```py
import pandas as pd

dataframe1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe1['Time'], unit='s')
dataframe1.index = dataframe1['Time']
x = dataframe1.resample('H').ohlc()
```

```py
Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information:
---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------
Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 199, in batch
    odfs = mod.azureml_main(*idfs)
  File "C:\temp\4cf09401e1994ec1a2112e2d81ef4ff3.py", line 49, in azureml_main
    x = dataframe1.resample('H').agg({
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1843, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'
Process returned with non-zero exit code 1
```

もしかして文法うんぬんというより実行環境が悪いのでしょうか...

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'` と表示されている事から、pandas のバージョンが 0.20.0 未満なのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

dataframe1は既に **OHLC形式**になっているように見えますが・・。

既に **OHLC形式**のデータを *Resample*　したいというのであれば、

```
x = dataframe1.resample('H').agg({
    'Open': 'first',
    'High': 'max',
    'Low': 'min',
    'Close': 'last'})
```

のようになるのではないでしょうか。

---

**【追記】**
そのままで動作する動作サンプルコードをあげておきます。
動作を確認してみてください。

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """
Time,Open,High,Low,Close
20170102 020100,116.875,116.915,116.875,116.901
20170102 020200,116.901,116.901,116.901,116.901
20170102 020300,116.901,116.906,116.897,116.900
"""

dataframe1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), parse_dates=['Time'],　index_col='Time')
res = dataframe1.resample('H').agg({
    'Open': 'first',
    'High': 'max',
    'Low': 'min',
    'Close': 'last'})

print(res)
#                         Low     High     Open  Close
#Time
#2017-01-02 02:00:00  116.875  116.915  116.875  116.9
```

Comment: 申し訳ありませんが、追記されたコードが前回のコードと同じものなので、どのようなコードを動作させた結果のエラーなのか確認できません（コピーミスでしょうか？）
とりあえず、動作サンプルを追加しましたので、自分のコードとの違いを確認してみてください。